# How to calculate the Von Neuman entropy on qiskit with the module quantum_info?

Tags: qiskit, programming, entropy

I am trying to wrap my head around he `quantum_info` module on qiskit, since most of the functions on `qiskit.tools` are going to be deprecated, but I am very confused with the Statevector and DensityMatrix objects. For example, with this snippet of code:

```
simulator = BasicAer.get_backend('statevector_simulator') # the device to run on
result6 = execute(circuit6, simulator).result()
outputstate6 = result6.get_statevector(circuit6, decimals=3)
probability = np.abs(np.array(outputstate6))**2
outstatevector=quantum_info.states.Statevector(outputstate6)
print(type(outstatevector))
print(type(outputstate6))
print(outputstate6)
print(quantum_info.entropy(outputstate6))
```

I get:

```
<class 'qiskit.quantum_info.states.statevector.Statevector'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[0.447+0.j 0.   +0.j 0.632+0.j 0.632+0.j]
```

as expected but then I get the error on `quantum_info.entropy(outputstate6)`:

```
QiskitError: 'Input quantum state is not a valid'
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Is it because you're giving it quantum_info.entropy(outputstate6), rather than quantum_info.entropy(outstatevector)? It looks like there's a check to see if it's a statevector rather than a numpy array - https://qiskit.org/documentation/_modules/qiskit/quantum_info/states/measures.html#entropy

Comment: I tried with the outstatevector and I still get the same error, that was the motivation to post this question here. I honestly don't know what is wrong. The same happened with the density matrix methods, some of them worked, some of them didn't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**

You are getting that error because your example does not use a valid (normalized) statevector. If you remove the `decimals=3` kwarg where you call `result.get_statevector` it will work.

**Long Answer**

The Von-Neuman `entropy` function in the `qiskit.quantum_info` works with either `Statevector` or `DensityMatrix` object inputs, or inputs that can be implicitly converted to those objects (ie a list or np.array for a vector or a square matrix). So you can do any of the following for example:

```
import numpy as np
from qiskit.quantum_info import entropy, Statevector, DensityMatrix

# Pure state entropy (Note this is always 0)
# The following are equivalent:

s1 = entropy([1, 0, 0, 0])  # Statevector as list
s2 = entropy(np.array([1, 0, 0, 0])) # Statevector as array
s3 = entropy(Statevector([1, 0, 0, 0]))  # Statevector object

print(s1, s2, s3)

# Mixed state entropy
# The following are equivalent

s1 = entropy([[0.75, 0], [0, 0.25]])  # Density matrix as list
s2 = entropy(np.array([[0.75, 0], [0, 0.25]])) # density matrix as array
s3 = entropy(DensityMatrix([[0.75, 0], [0, 0.25]]))  # Density matrix object

print(s1, s2, s3)
```

As for your specific issue: the entropy is only well-defined for a valid quantum state, so the function checks the input state is valid. In the case of a statevector this is checking it has norm 1, in the case of a density matrix that it is trace 1 and postive-semidefinite.

Your example does not have a norm-1 input state because you truncated the decimals when you got the output state from the simulator. You can check this using the statevector object for example:

```
# Returns True:
Statevector([1 / np.sqrt(2), 1 / np.sqrt(2)]).is_valid()

# Returns False:
Statevector([0.707, 0.707]).is_valid()
```

*Entropy base:* Another thing you should keep in mind if you didn't already notice is that the `qiskit.quantum_info.entropy` function takes logarithms in base 2 by default (and you can use a different base using the `base` kwarg). The deprecated `qiskit.tools.qi.entropy` function was always taken in log base `e`:

````
import numpy as np
from qiskit.quantum_info import entropy
from qiskit.tools.qi import entropy as old_entropy

rho = [[0.75, 0], [0, 0.25]]

s1 = entropy(rho)  # base-2
s2 = entropy(rho, base=np.e)  # base-e
s3 = old_entropy(rho)  # base-e

print(s1, s2, s3, s2 == s3)
```
````